# Unable to open images or play videos of third party app in Android 11

Tags: android, uri

I send an Intent to the WhatsApp statuses folder. I got Uri of that particular folder in onActivityResult. This is how I'm reading that Intent

```
private void readFiles(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Uri uriTree = intent.getData();
        Uri uriFolder = DocumentsContract.buildChildDocumentsUriUsingTree(uriTree, DocumentsContract.getTreeDocumentId(uriTree));

        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
            cursor = contentResolver.query(uriFolder,
                    new String[]{DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_DOCUMENT_ID},
                    null, null, null);

            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    Uri uriFile = DocumentsContract.buildDocumentUriUsingTree(uriTree, cursor.getString(0));
                    File file = new File(uriFile.getPath());
                    if (file.getName().endsWith(".gif") || file.getName().endsWith(".mp4")) {
                        fileArrayList.add(file);
                        Log.i("TAG", "readFiles: " + fileArrayList.get(0).getAbsolutePath());
                    }

                } while (cursor.moveToNext());

            }
            popuLateReyclerView(fileArrayList);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle error
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) cursor.close();
        }
    }
```

By doing this way files are being displayed in recyclerview but no thumbnail is available and when I click to play a video it displays a message can't play video. Kindly guide me on how can I achieve this

Comment: `send an Intent to the WhatsApp statuses folder` ??? What are you doing? How?

Comment: `Uri uriFile = DocumentsContract.buildDocumentUriUsingTree(uriTree, cursor.getString(0));` You cannot use that function to get an uri for a file. Try better.
`File file = new File(uriFile.getPath());` Even if you had a nice uri for a file you cannot use the File class to access it. (Indeed you can use it to obtain a file name but thats all).